# Coffeescript: Rails way of date functions - beginning & end of year/month/week

Tags: date, coffeescript

I was going around coffescript and couldn't find any good library for working with date functions like in Rails

so I wrote something that may help you with getting your job done.

If you find better way, comment please :)

Usage:

```
(new Date()).endOfMonth()
#=> Fri Feb 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

(new Date()).subMonths(2).beginningOfMonth()
#=> Sat Dec 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Lib:

```
Date::yesterday = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), @getDate()-1)

Date::beginningOfYear = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), 1, 1)

Date::endOfYear = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear()+1, 0, 0)

Date::beginningOfMonth = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), 1)

Date::endOfMonth = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth()+1, 0)

Date::beginningOfWeek = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), @getDate() - @getDay() + 1)  

Date::endOfWeek = () ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), @getDate() + (7-@getDay()))  

Date::addYears = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear() + count, @getMonth(), @getDate())  

Date::addMonths = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth() + count, @getDate())  

Date::addDays = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), @getDate() + count)  

Date::subYears = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear() - count, @getMonth(), @getDate())  

Date::subMonths = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth() - count, @getDate())  

Date::subDays = (count) ->
  new Date(1900+@getYear(), @getMonth(), @getDate() - count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with time I can't really recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) enough.